# Finding the True Source of an Error in a Single Error Handler

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA in Excel for Microsoft 365.

The processing I perform on my input data is time-consuming. Therefore, I have the following procedure to enable speed optimizations:

```
Sub SetSpeedOptimizations(Enable As Boolean)
    If Enable = True Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

As can be seen below, I enable speed optimizations before the time-consuming processing (inside **bar()**) and then disable speed optimizations after processing.

```
Sub foo()
    SetSpeedOptimizations True

    ' Ensure speed optimizations get turned off in the event of an error
    On Error GoTo RestoreSpeedOptimizationsUponError

    ...
    ...

    ' An error thrown inside bar() will not show up in bar().
    ' It will show up in the RestoreSpeedOptimizationsUponError error handler below.
    ' How can I see the true source of the error and still ensure
    ' that SetSpeedOptimizations False gets called?
    bar() ' Time-consuming processing happens inside bar()

    ...
    ...

    SetSpeedOptimizations False
    On Error GoTo 0

    Exit Sub
RestoreSpeedOptimizationsUponError:
    SetSpeedOptimizations False

    ' Re-raise the error so the user sees it and so the application aborts
    ' This is where the user sees the error, not down in bar()
    Err.Raise Err.Number

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The problem comes when an error is thrown within **bar()**.

The desired effect of ensuring speed optimizations are disabled before **foo()** exits is achieved, but the source of the error is masked. An error that is thrown in **bar()** is seen only in the error handler in **foo()**.

When I throw an error, I do so as follows:

```
' object.Raise number, source, description, helpfile, helpcontext
Err.Raise 10, , "My error message"
```

As can be seen, I provide the required error **number** and the optional **description**. I omit the optional **source** (and the optional help-related parameters).

A partial solution would be to populate **source** with the module, procedure name, and line number.

### First Question

How may I populate **source** with the module, procedure name, and line number without hard-coding them?

### Second Question

Even if I start populating **source** as described above, I still will have lost **bar()**'s call stack entry and won't be able to see its local variable values so as to debug what caused the error.

Furthermore, **bar()** has many procedure calls in it, those in turn have many procedure calls, etc. The call tree is wide and deep. If possible, I'd like to avoid putting an error handler in every function.

Is it possible to ensure that 1) speed optimizations are disabled before **foo()** exits, **and** the true source of the error (in **bar()**) is shown? The way I'm approaching it does not seem like it can be made to work.

Comment: If you place `on error resume next` inside bar() upon an error, it will just continue. this at least ensures that you get out of bar(). But you probably want to catch the error in bar() to ensure that it never happens in the first place. Alternatively, create an errorhandler on bar() that also disables the speed optimization

Comment: This guy gives a good VBA error handling model that shows the flow - https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#:~:text=Error%20Handling%20is%20used%20to,of%20the%20error%20from%20Err. (Ignore any pop-ups for paid for products)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. By the time you have caught the exception in `foo`, you have already exited `bar`, so there are no local `bar` variables to debug. You never had a meaningful `Source` either.

Comment: As stated by @CHill60 I think to define how you're going to handle errors will be useful, not only for this, but for your coding in general. IE: Can it be turned to a function and handle somehow your own error messages using some pattern? (Err01MyFunc: Desc) Exit. Is it an execution that should halt completly if it doesn't perform? (Err01Exec: Desc) End. Some may agree and some may disagree but I think this will benefit your coding and these kind of scenarios. The code optimizations in this sense are just an extension

Comment: If you have an operation that may return an error that operation should be encapsulated inside its own try function.  That way you as the programmer keep control of what is happening.  As you haven't provided the code which may cause an error I can't make any code suggestions.